# Best Way to Invoke Any Cross-Threaded Code?

Tags: c#, .net, invoke

I know that this question has been asked before, but I'm looking for a way to:

1. streamline the creation of safe cross-threaded code.
2. reuse this code in any situation (no Windows Forms references).

Here's what I have so far, but I want to remove the Windows Forms references. Any ideas?

```
public delegate void SafeInvokeDelegate(System.Action action);
public class SafeInvoke
{
    private readonly System.Windows.Forms.Control _threadControl;

    public SafeInvoke()
    {
        _threadControl = new System.Windows.Forms.Control();
    }

    public void Invoke(System.Action action)
    {
        if (_threadControl.InvokeRequired)
            _threadControl.Invoke(new SafeInvokeDelegate(Invoke), new object[] {action});
        else if (action != null) action();
    }
}
```

The above class might be used this way:

```
SafeInvoke _safeInvoker = new SafeInvoke();
void SafeClearItems()
{
    _safeInvoker.Invoke(delegate
        {
            listView1.Items.Clear();
        });
}
```

How would I remove the System.Windows.Forms.Control in the SafeInvoke class but keep the same functionality?

Comment: Note that the docs surrounding Invoke() on Control are actually pretty subtle. I don't believe a generic class is sufficient for Control because of the interaction with IsHandleCreated and IsDisposed (unless you always check those first in your SafeInvokeDelegate).  ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714666/ )

Comment: Thanks for sharing this class. Helped me to solve my problems..

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You also could use an extension method and lambdas to make your code much cleaner.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
public static class ISynchronizeInvokeExtensions
{
  public static void InvokeEx<T>(this T @this, Action<T> action) where T : ISynchronizeInvoke
  {
    if (@this.InvokeRequired)
    {
      @this.Invoke(action, new object[] { @this });
    }
    else
    {
      action(@this);
    }
  }
}
```

So now you can use `InvokeEx` on any ISynchronizeInvoke and be able to access the properties and fields of implementing class.

```
this.InvokeEx(f => f.listView1.Items.Clear());
```

Comment: It may seem obvious, but you also need to add the "System" namespace

Comment: This is an awesome idea.  I did it in VB.net and also have 4 overloads for Subroutines/Functions/WithParams/WithoutParams.  VB.net is able to infer the generic types.

Comment: why not simply `listView1.InvokeEx(lv => lv.Items.Clear());`?

Comment: This piece of code is fabulistastic. Makes my code nice and clean and easy! As Mark who reminded me of Gump said - Samuel you are a Genius!   I like it especially because it works!

Comment: Can someone please show me what I need to do to incorporate this code in my own form?

I have a FormMain (My mainform), I put the block of code in my FormMain.cs class (outside of class FormMain). I got a weird error on the FormMain.designer.cs about not finding the "$this.icon".

Comment: @jgauffin Some controls may not implement ISynchronizeInvoke so you cannot use this extension method on them directly. Ex. ToolStripStatusLabel does not implement ISynchronizeInvoke.

Comment: @arman: you can change the `T` restriction to `Control` or similar if that fits your use case better.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`ISynchronizeInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke.aspx) instead of `Control`. That's the interface that `Control` implements with `Invoke/BeginInvoke/EndInvoke/InvokeRequired`.

An alternative is to use [`SynchronizationContext.Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current.aspx) - which is what `BackgroundWorker` uses, I believe.

Comment: Could you show a code example? :-) Implementing ISynchronizeInvoke requires BeginInvoke, etc, and could get tedious.

Comment: Looks like ISynchronizeInvoke is implemented only by Control class. This doesn't looke like a way to get rid of Windows Forms dependency.

Comment: No code example is required. You just replace System.Windows.Forms.Control with System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke.

Comment: @XOR: ISynchronizeInvoke is in the System assembly, I don't think you will need to reference the Forms assembly.

Comment: @XOR: Confirmed, ISynchronizeInvoke only requires a reference to the System library.

Answer (score 8):

Nowadays it's easy to Invoke.
e.g. Say we want to invoke a Label(lblVal) to get value of txtVal

```
lblVal.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate{lblVal.Text = txtVal.Text;});
```

...it's as easy as that :D

Comment: What a great, straightforward solution. Thank you

Comment: This works perfectly.  Just needed to capitalize `invoke` --> `Invoke`.

Answer (score 5):

Here it is in VB.net, very similar to Samuel's answer.  I have four overloads depending on whether you want a subroutine or function and whether or not there's a parameter.  It would be easy to add more overloads for more parameters.  VB.Net is able to infer the types.

```
Module ISynchronizeInvokeExtensions
    Public Delegate Function GenericLambdaFunctionWithParam(Of InputType, OutputType)(ByVal input As InputType) As OutputType
    Private Delegate Function InvokeLambdaFunctionCallback(Of InputType, OutputType)(ByVal f As GenericLambdaFunctionWithParam(Of InputType, OutputType), ByVal input As InputType, ByVal c As System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke) As OutputType
    Public Function InvokeEx(Of InputType, OutputType)(ByVal f As GenericLambdaFunctionWithParam(Of InputType, OutputType), ByVal input As InputType, ByVal c As System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke) As OutputType
        If c.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As New InvokeLambdaFunctionCallback(Of InputType, OutputType)(AddressOf InvokeEx)
            Return DirectCast(c.Invoke(d, New Object() {f, input, c}), OutputType)
        Else
            Return f(input)
        End If
    End Function

    Public Delegate Sub GenericLambdaSubWithParam(Of InputType)(ByVal input As InputType)
    Public Sub InvokeEx(Of InputType)(ByVal s As GenericLambdaSubWithParam(Of InputType), ByVal input As InputType, ByVal c As System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke)
        InvokeEx(Of InputType, Object)(Function(i As InputType) As Object
                                           s(i)
                                           Return Nothing
                                       End Function, input, c)
    End Sub

    Public Delegate Sub GenericLambdaSub()
    Public Sub InvokeEx(ByVal s As GenericLambdaSub, ByVal c As System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke)
        InvokeEx(Of Object, Object)(Function(i As Object) As Object
                                        s()
                                        Return Nothing
                                    End Function, Nothing, c)
    End Sub

    Public Delegate Function GenericLambdaFunction(Of OutputType)() As OutputType
    Public Function InvokeEx(Of OutputType)(ByVal f As GenericLambdaFunction(Of OutputType), ByVal c As System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke) As OutputType
        Return InvokeEx(Of Object, OutputType)(Function(i As Object) f(), Nothing, c)
    End Function
End Module
```

Usage (run this in a backgroundworker):

```
    InvokeEx(Sub(x As String) Me.Text = x, "foo", Me) 'set form title to foo
    InvokeEx(AddressOf MsgBox, Me.Text, Me)
    InvokeEx(Sub() Me.Text &= "!", "foo", Me) 'append "!" to form title
    InvokeEx(AddressOf MsgBox, Me.Text, Me)
    Dim s As String = InvokeEx(Function() Me.Text, Me) & "bar" 'get form title to backgorundworker thread
    InvokeEx(AddressOf MsgBox, s, Me) 'display the string from backgroundworker thread
```

Comment: Hi. I've have been using your code above with great success, but I tested my program on a few computers. It has worked correctly on most of the Win XP computers that I've tested it on, but on one of them I get the following error: "Commom Language Runtime detected an invalid program". Do you know how to solve this? I am using .NET framework V2.

Comment: Try upgrading the CLR?  I think that Sub lambda is supported only by .Net 4, before there there was only Function lambda.

Comment: That doesn't look similar to Samuel's answer to me. You are creating delegates. He uses Lambdas instead of delegates. I will post the VB code that i use in my own answer.

Comment: The code that I wrote is quite old.  At the time, I think that VB.Net didn't have full lambda support.

Answer (score 4):

here's the VB equivalent code to Samuel's answer that i use. notice i actually have 2 extensions functions, but i must admit i don't know why they are there. i copied my C# version years ago (maybe from this site) and it had both extension functions, but for what reason, i don't fully understand. i just copied it and how to use it, and i half understand all that goes on 'under the hood' with these complicated functions.

```
#Const System_ComponentModel = True
#Const System_Drawing = False

Option Compare Binary
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On

Imports System.Collections
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices ' for Extension() attribute
Imports System.Text
#If System_ComponentModel Then
Imports System.ComponentModel
#End If
#If System_Drawing Then
Imports System.Drawing
#End If

Public Module MyExtensions

    ' other #Region blocks are removed. i use many in my Extensions
    ' module/class. the below code is only the 2 relevant extension
    ' for this 'SafeInvoke' functionality. but i use other regions
    ' such as "String extensions" and "Numeric extensions". i use
    ' the above System_ComponentModel and System_Drawing compiler
    ' directives to include or exclude blocks of code that i want
    ' to either include or exclude in a project, which allows me to
    ' easily compare my code in one project with the same file in
    ' other projects to syncronise new changes across projects.
    ' you can scrap pretty much all the code above,
    ' but i'm giving it here so you see it in the full context.

    #Region "ISynchronizeInvoke extensions"

    #If System_ComponentModel Then

        <Extension()>
        Public Function SafeInvoke(Of T As ISynchronizeInvoke, TResult)(isi As T, callFunction As Func(Of T, TResult)) As TResult
            If (isi.InvokeRequired) Then
                Dim result As IAsyncResult = isi.BeginInvoke(callFunction, New Object() {isi})
                Dim endresult As Object = isi.EndInvoke(result)
                Return DirectCast(endresult, TResult)
            Else
                Return callFunction(isi)
            End If
        End Function

        ''' <summary>
        ''' This can be used in VB with:
        ''' txtMyTextBox.SafeInvoke(Sub(d) d.Text = "This is my new Text value.")
        ''' or:
        ''' txtMyTextBox.SafeInvoke(Sub(d) d.Text = myTextStringVariable)
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        ''' <param name="isi"></param>
        ''' <param name="callFunction"></param>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        <Extension()>
        Public Sub SafeInvoke(Of T As ISynchronizeInvoke)(isi As T, callFunction As Action(Of T))
            If isi.InvokeRequired Then
                isi.BeginInvoke(callFunction, New Object() {isi})
            Else
                callFunction(isi)
            End If
        End Sub

    #End If

    #End Region

    ' other #Region blocks are removed from here too.

End Module
```

And the C# version is:

```
#define System_ComponentModel
#undef  System_Drawing

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

#if System_ComponentModel
using System.ComponentModel;
#endif
#if System_Drawing
using System.Drawing;
#endif

namespace MyCompany.Extensions
{
    static partial class MyExtensions
    {

        // other #Region blocks are removed. i use many in my Extensions
        // module/class. the below code is only the 2 relevant extension
        // for this 'SafeInvoke' functionality. but i use other regions
        // such as "String extensions" and "Numeric extensions". i use
        // the above System_ComponentModel and System_Drawing compiler
        // directives to include or exclude blocks of code that i want
        // to either include or exclude in a project, which allows me to
        // easily compare my code in one project with the same file in
        // other projects to syncronise new changes across projects.
        // you can scrap pretty much all the code above,
        // but i'm giving it here so you see it in the full context.

        #region ISynchronizeInvoke extensions
#if System_ComponentModel

        public static TResult SafeInvoke<T, TResult>(this T isi, Func<T, TResult> callFunction) where T : ISynchronizeInvoke
        {
            if (isi.InvokeRequired)
            {
                IAsyncResult result = isi.BeginInvoke(callFunction, new object[] { isi });
                object endResult = isi.EndInvoke(result); return (TResult)endResult;
            }
            else
                return callFunction(isi);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This can be used in C# with:
        /// txtMyTextBox.SafeInvoke(d => d.Text = "This is my new Text value.");
        /// or:
        /// txtMyTextBox.SafeInvoke(d => d.Text = myTextStringVariable);
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="isi"></param>
        /// <param name="callFunction"></param>
        public static void SafeInvoke<T>(this T isi, Action<T> callFunction) where T : ISynchronizeInvoke
        {
            if (isi.InvokeRequired) isi.BeginInvoke(callFunction, new object[] { isi });
            else
                callFunction(isi);
        }

#endif
        #endregion

        // other #Region blocks are removed from here too.

    } // static class MyExtensions

} // namespace
```

Happy coding!

Comment: Very useful; specially the extension that works with return result. +1