# C#: how to update winform from thread?

Tags: c#, winforms

A C# thread (Read()) causes System.NotSupportedException when it tries to update a winform based on received content.
The full error message is

> Read() System.NotSupportedException:
>   An error message cannot be displayed
>   because an optional resource assembly
>   containing it cannot be found at
>   Microsoft.AGL.Common.MISC.HandelAr() 
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar._SetInfo()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar.set_Value()
>   at ...ProcessStatus() at ...Read()

The Build/Target Environment is: `Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v2.0\WindowsCE`. Is the problem writing to the ProgressBar from a Thread?
If so, what is the correct C#/winforms method to update a ProgressBar from a Thread? In this application the Read() Thread is continuous: it is started when the application starts and runs forever.

```
void ProcessStatus(byte[] status)
{
    Status.Speed = status[5];
    var Speed = Status.Speed/GEAR_RATIO;
    Status.Speed = (int) Speed;
    progressBarSpeed.Value = Status.Speed;
    ...
```

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c

Comment: You should look into installing System_SR_ENU_wm.CAB or something similar that will enable you to get the error messages on your platform.  To save space they usually don't include all the error messages on devices.

Comment: The anonymous method by Marc Gravell in Gratzy's link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c/661662) seemed to be the simplest solution for this problem.

this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
    someLabel.Text = newText; // runs on UI thread
});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use `Invoke` to make changes to controls created in the Gui Thread.

To make life easier, take a look at some of the [extension methods provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711408/best-way-to-invoke-any-cross-threaded-code/711419#711419)

Answer (score 2):

You should call `Control.BeginInvoke`