# C# Error doing stuff with 2 objects of 2 different process

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, controls

i have 2 classes in different threads,"A" and "B".
"A" creates Windows forms controls and "B" is the GUI thread.
At some point "A" listens to an event fired in "B" then it uses:

```
      MethodInvoker m22 = new MethodInvoker(() => flow.Controls.Add(myobj));
        flow.Invoke(m22);
```

That adds "myobj" thats created in "A" to flow thats a control created in "B".

The error: I get an error because its accessing myobj from a different process that the process where it was created.

Is the event starting a new process? Thanks

Comment: What is the exact exception you get?

Comment: Hmm Control.Invoke ?

Comment: Invoking and using delegates is the right direction, but you may doing it wrong. Would you add an example how you do this?

Comment: @ZorgoZ the error is System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: @LauC ok, and what is the message? You can see it under Details in VS.

Comment: Are you sure that error message mentioned process? Didn't it say *thread* instead? Because then this can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7609839/578411