# Create Instance of a Class on New Thread

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating an instance of a class that is in DLL and can't be modified.
It loads images and it takes long time which freezes the WinForms UI.

Can I instantiate the class on a new thread?

```cs
var images = new AppImages(); // This to execute on new thread?
var cboData = new List<string>();
foreach(var image in images)
{
    cboData.Add(image); 
}
comboBox.DataSource = cboData;
```

I am trying to use

```cs
private void My()
{
    var images = ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(GetAppImages);
     
    var cboData = new List<string>();
    foreach(var image in images)
    {
        cboData.Add(image); 
    }
    comboBox.DataSource = cboData;
}

private AppImages GetAppImages()
{
    return new AppImages();
}
```

but the threadPool doesn't return any value, it is just executing the code and I need the new instance to work with it later in the code.

Also, I can call the entire logic in a new thread because there are UI elements (the comboBox for example).

Comment: We'd really need to know more about the class. Does it contain any UI components, or is it just data? Does it have any thread-sensitive behavior?

Comment: Have you tried it? Does AppImages create ui elements (control etc)

Comment: The class is just data, the issue is to return the new instance from the ThreadPool.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing a form's control from a separate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609839/accessing-a-forms-control-from-a-separate-thread)

Comment: No, it is not related and not applicable to my case. Thera are too many UI elements involved.

Comment: Another thread does not mean your UI will not block, since you want to *wait* for it to use it's result. You will need to restructure your whole method and have some kind of BackgroundWorker and Waiting Dialog/UI.

Comment: @nvoigt: The UI can still be responsive even if some operation is awaiting a result.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sure, but it is extra work. At least the function needs to be async, which means there needs to be some additional logic that the user cannot just click other things while it runs.

Comment: @nvoigt: Why does there need to be additional logic? We don't know whether the application actually needs to prevent other things from being used while the combobox is being populated or not. In my experience a lot of the time it's fine to just let the rest of the UI be usable - but it entirely depends on the application.

Comment: @JonSkeet I would assume that the App should at least block the user from clicking on the button multiple times, if it's a long running, costly operation. I haven't done WinForms in a long time, last time I checked UI callbacks were still expecting sync handlers, so putting in an async handler might cause problems in other functions the user could now reach, since the program no longer blocks. That is not a problem with async per se and your solution is absolutely correct, I'm just saying: there probably is extra work to be done now syncronising the rest for any non trivial program.

Comment: @nvoigt: What button? The OP never mentioned a button. Even if it *is* in response to a button, async/await makes that really easy - just disable the button at the start of the method, and re-enable it in a finally block. It's absolutely fine to write async event handlers, and *much, much* simpler than trying to manage everything via callbacks.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't disagree. I just said they need to be aware of it, that the method is now non-blocking when the return value is ignored, it was blocking before under those circumstances and since that is the normal way WinForms calls it's event handlers, they need to adjust their application if it implicitly build on that blocking behaviour.

Comment: @nvoigt: Well, you also said "You will need to restructure your whole method and have some kind of BackgroundWorker and Waiting Dialog/UI" - and I still think that's inaccurate. Yes, the application needs to be designed with this sort of asynchrony in mind, but there's no need for BackgroundWorker and I don't think we should *assume* there's any need for a waiting dialog.

Comment: @JonSkeet Okay, fair enough. In my mind, an async method is "some kind" of Background worker. I didn't mean to imply they need to use that exact class and it's mechanisms. There is indeed no technical neccessity to change anything, it's just what is needed in my experience in the programs I wrote. Because my users complain when nothing happens and no progress dialog shows and my users click everywhere in the meantime instead of just being patient. Others may have better users and I am a little envious of that :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest using `Task.Run` to initialize `AppImages` in a different thread, and await that task from the UI thread. So:

```cs
public async Task My()
{
    Task<AppImages> task = Task.Run(() => new AppImages());
    var images = await task;
    comboBox.DataSource = images.Images.ToList();
}
```

The use of `await` here means that the last line of the method still runs on the UI thread - but it won't block the UI while the task is running.

Comment: It's compact! it's working! The images are loaded, the combo box is populated like before and the UI doesn't freeze while loading!
Accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Invoke`. This can be used by non-UI threads to access UI elements (via the UI thread). This is done because only the UI thread can interact with UI elements.

Here's an example of the creation of a new thread, and waiting for 10 seconds just to pretend it is doing work, but after waiting (e.g. when the results/images are ready), and we want to modify UI elements we use `Invoke`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Task.Run(() => {
        // load stuff that takes time: simulate by sleeping for 10 seconds
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        
        var newText = "new button text";

        // now we want to change something in the UI, we use Invoke.
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => {
            this.button1.Text = newText;
        }));
    });
}
```

Comment: I would expect it to be simpler to use async/await - in a UI method, create a task that initializes the data in a new thread, and await that, then use the value.

Comment: I tried using async/await but the class/method that I am calling is in DLL and is not Async. When I call await it won't work.

Comment: @st_stefanov: That doesn't mean you can't use async/await - it means you need to create a task yourself. See my answer. (But if you don't understand async/await, I strongly suggest you read more about it first...)

Comment: Well, I do understand what you mean in the last explanation. Thank you!

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree async/await is better/cleaner/simpler than using `.Invoke` +1, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap this code in a method and can call that method using

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run()
```

eg

```
void LoadData()
{ 

   var images = new AppImages(); // This to execute on new thread?
   var cboData = new List<string>();
   foreach(var image in images)
   {
      cboData.Add(image); 
   }
   comboBox.DataSource = cboData;
}
```

and call it like this

```
Task.Run(() => LoadData());
```

Please refer the doc from Microsoft
[Task.Run Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Yeah, that is the first thing I tried. The comboBox is a UI control and it will crash when a new thread tries to 'touch' it.

Comment: @st_stefanov https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609839/accessing-a-forms-control-from-a-separate-thread

Comment: Thanks, I also tried this, but there are too many UI controls involved.

Comment: Then create a method in the form to handle the request.

Comment: Only the UI thread can access UI elements so this won't work. You can ask the framework to run code on the UI thread from another thread like I explain in my answer

Comment: Yeah, looks like the answer will be a combination of both answers here.

Comment: I tried and in combination with the Invoke from another answer here, this does work. However, the code gets a bit bulky.