# Change button color from other thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

In my c# program I create a bunch of buttons in the main (UI) thread. Then I start a timer that runs a method `Timeline()`. Now I want the appearance of the buttons to change when the `Timeline()` method runs. But I'm not allowed to access the objects because they are owned by the main thread. How do I solve this?

Error: `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

I have found `Dispatcher disp = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;` which has an `Invoke()` method but I'm not sure if that is the right way, and I couldn't get it to work.

Here is part of my code:

```
    private static SurfaceButton[,] buttons = new SurfaceButton[dimensionBeats, dimensionsNotes];

    public SurfaceWindow1()
    {
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }


        LoadAudioContent();
        // Add handlers for Application activation events
        AddActivationHandlers();


        InitializeButtons();

        try
        {
            t = new Timer(Timeline, null, 1, dimensionBeats*500);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        } 
    }

    private void InitializeButtons()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                SurfaceButton btn = new SurfaceButton();
                //btn.Content = files[j].Substring(0,1);
                btn.Name = "a" +i + j;
                btn.Width = 120;
                btn.Height = 120;
                btn.ContactEnter+=StartSound;
                btn.ContactLeave+=StopSound;
                btn.Opacity = 0.01;
                btn.ClickMode = ClickMode.Release;

                buttons[i,j] = btn;

                // add the newly generated button to the correct column (left to right one panel per column)
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        rowPanel0.Children.Add(btn);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        rowPanel1.Children.Add(btn);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        rowPanel2.Children.Add(btn);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        rowPanel3.Children.Add(btn);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        rowPanel4.Children.Add(btn);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        rowPanel5.Children.Add(btn);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        rowPanel6.Children.Add(btn);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        rowPanel7.Children.Add(btn);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void Timeline(Object state)
    {     

        for (int i = 0; i < pressed.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            sendRequest(url, postMethod, tabelId, buttsToString(butts));

            for (int j = 0; j < pressed.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                if (pressed[i,j])
                {
                    buttons[i, j].Background = Brushes.Red;
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            for (int j = 0; j < pressed.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                buttons[i, j].Background = Brushes.White;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This should answer your question: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the?rq=1>

Comment: Following page gives you a good solution.

[Best Way to Invoke Any Cross-Threaded Code][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711408/best-way-to-invoke-any-cross-threaded-code/711419

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms?

Comment: It is WPF, I'm programming on a Microsoft Surface (1.0) in Visual studio using C# and XAML

Comment: @Niels: Then the `Dispatcher` member on the `Button` should be what you need. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `Invoke/BeginInvoke` to forward updates to the GUI thread:

```
int i1 = i; // local copies to avoid closure bugs
int j1 = j;
buttons[i1, j1].Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    ((Action)(() => buttons[i1, j1].Background = Brushes.Red)));
```

Comment: Then I get the error: A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in CoffeeTable1.exe.

Comment: @Niels: I suspect the problem is variable capture. Check my edited code.

Comment: You were right. Thanks! I never heard of variable capture before. Any suggestion where to learn how and why it works?

Comment: @Niels: Here's the definitive blog post about this common issue: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx And sorry for the terminology, it's actually closure, not capture. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it-

```
Button1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate {
// Executes the following code on the GUI thread.
Button1.BackColor="Red";}));
```

Comment: If I try this one I get: Error 3 'Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Controls.SurfaceButton' does not contain a definition for 'Invoke' and no extension method 'Invoke' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Controls.SurfaceButton' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: This is how you usually do it with the controls in .NET. Sorry but no idea of Surface Buttons and Microsoft surface.

Comment: This is the WinForms version. He's using WPF.

Comment: I think it should have been `this.Dispatcher.Invoke(`

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the access to the button or the whole (loop around it) with

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate
{
    // TODO: Implement task to do on main thread
});
```

Controls must always be accessed on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Yes will need to make use of `Invoke` method. It executes the specified delegate synchronously on the thread the Dispatcher is associated with.