# What is the best way to update UI in multiThread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, uiapplicationdelegate

I have three class, tow of them was UI class, in the mainForm class, I start a new form by execute

```
new LoginForm.ShowDialog();
```

in the LoginForm class, I write code about log in and log out, when the use loged in, I start a new thread to check if something need to be done,and update the databases; and here is the question, I don't know how to update a label that in the MainForm 
I search this question and they told me I should to use Delegate.but it really puzzled me a lot cause they don't in a same class so I don't know how to use Delegate cross thread and cross different
Until now, my code is like this
MainForm.cs:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
        public delegate void testDelegate();
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void msg(string s)
        {
            label.Test = s;
        }
}
```

LoginForm.cs:

```
JobDoer jD = new JobDoer();
Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(jD.run));
t2.Start();
```

JobDoer:

```
public void run()
 {
     //tD();
     tD = new MainForm.testDelegate(MainForm.msg);
     //this.
     Thread.Sleep(1000);
     return;
}
```

what should I do next?

Comment: UI elements can be modified only by UI thread. So invoke UI thread using dispatcher from another thread when you need modification.

Comment: could you please give me some demo?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx And depending what you use something should be holding property of this type that allows invoking UI thread.

Comment: See the answers to similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Taken from: [Best Way to Invoke Any Cross-Threaded Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711408/best-way-to-invoke-any-cross-threaded-code)

You also could use an extension method and lambdas to make your code much cleaner.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
public static class ISynchronizeInvokeExtensions
{
  public static void InvokeEx<T>(this T @this, Action<T> action) where T : ISynchronizeInvoke
  {
    if (@this.InvokeRequired)
    {
      @this.Invoke(action, new object[] { @this });
    }
    else
    {
      action(@this);
    }
  }
}
```

So now you can use `InvokeEx` on any ISynchronizeInvoke and be able to access the properties and fields of implementing class.

```
this.InvokeEx(f => f.listView1.Items.Clear());
```

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of thing theres the
System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker class. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-implement-a-form-that-uses-a-background-operation.
It handles the thread sync for you, plus it has a usefull prgress update event