# Is InvokeRequired required?

Tags: c#, invoke

My coworker likes to do this

```
if (!listbox1.InvokeRequired)
    listbox1.Items.Add(Container.error_message);
else
    listbox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        listbox1.Items.Add(Container.error_message);
    });
```

Why do he have to check for InvokedRequired? Will it be better to just use this statement only?

```
    listbox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        listbox1.Items.Add(Container.error_message);
    });
```

Comment: Is there threading involved?

Comment: yes threading is involved

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are confident that a particular route can *only* be reached by a callback thread, then I'd be inclined to agree with you - not really for the purpose of avoiding the `Invoke`, but simply to avoid any duplication. If a path can be reached from multiple routes, it may be preferable to have the check to avoid any overheads in the non-threaded case, but: refactoring so that each code-path knows what it is doing (just calling a utility method) may be preferable, i.e. the UI thread just calls `Foo()`, where as the worker thread uses `Invoke` / `MethodInvoker` to call `Foo()`.

Comment: +1 I like the utility method route that does the check on `InvokeRequired` and handles accordingly

Comment: @jordanhill123 that isn't quite what I was suggesting actually

Comment: I agree with your statement but a utility or extension method such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367718/automating-the-invokerequired-code-pattern or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711408/best-way-to-invoke-any-cross-threaded-code can prevent code duplication.

Answer (score 2):

If you know for sure that the method will be called from a non-GUI thread there's no point in using InvokeRequired.

Furthermore, you could put that `listbox1.Items.Add(Container.error_message);` into a method  (DRY - don't repeat yourself). That method could be called without InvokeRequired from the GUI and by Invoke from a background thread.

Finally, (if at all) the usual pattern would be like so:

```
void AddMessageToListBox(String message)
{
    if (listbox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        listbox1.Invoke((Action<String>)AddMessageToListBox, message);
        return;
    }

    listbox1.Items.Add(message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `InvokeRequired` check makes the code work both when run by the GUI thread (executing the first if block) and when run by a non-GUI-thread (the second part of the block).

It looks a bit complicated but if by design the code could be run by either thread it makes sense, at least the `Invoke` will be necessary. As far as I remember you could choose to use `Invoke` only as you suggest, it would work when run by the GUI thread, too, but it is probably slightly less efficient. You could possibly argue that this is micro-optimization though - but I suggest that you simply test what happens in either case and how much time it consumes.

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Generic delegate for cross thread processing
    private void SetProperty<T>(Control ctrl, string propertyName, T propertyValue)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
            ctrl.Invoke((Action<Control, string, T>)SetProperty, ctrl, propertyName, propertyValue);
        else
        {
            var property = ctrl.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
            property.SetValue(ctrl, propertyValue);
        }
    }

    public object DataSource
    {
        set
        {
            SetProperty(treeView, "DataSource", value);
        }
    }
```