# Fast dynamic invoke between assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

**Invoker.csproj -> Program.cs**

```cs
namespace InvokeLibrary
{
    public class Invoke
    {
        public static void Invoker(Delegate method, params object[] data)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                method.DynamicInvoke(data);
        }
    }
}
```

**Caller.csproj -> Program.cs**

```cs
using InvokeLibrary;

object obj = new A("Message from caller");
Invoke.Invoker(ToBeInvoked, obj);

void ToBeInvoked(A obj) =>
    Console.WriteLine("A: " + obj.Message);
record A(string Message);
```

What would be the most efficient way for the library to invoke given delegates?
The library will call the same methods multiple times and the given data will always match the function's parameters.
Is there a way to improve performance or make the call less 'dynamic' trading for a slow overhead? Functions will be called many times so I don't mind if the first invoke will be slow.
I know about `MethodInfo.Invoke` but it takes too much memory to store in a list and `Delegate.DynamicInvoke` is too slow for my requirements

Comment: I am not sure of efficiency for your particular usage, but this is the simplest implementation of invoke I have found and have used for years: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711408/best-way-to-invoke-any-cross-threaded-code.  (I use the Samuel answer and jgauffin's comment for the usage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the EfficientInvoker implementation from Tom Dupont which he claims is 10 times faster than Delegate.DynamicInvoke

GitHub path:
https://github.com/tdupont750/tact.net/blob/master/framework/src/Tact/Reflection/EfficientInvoker.cs

The Tests class contains examples of usage:
https://github.com/tdupont750/tact.net/blob/master/framework/tests/Tact.Tests/Reflection/EfficientInvokerTests.cs